# Nullspace and transpose of $T$ given $Tf(y)=\int_0^1 (y-x)f(x)dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, linear-transformations

> Consider the linear operator $T:L^2((0,1))\to L^2((0,1))$ defined by
> $$
> Tf(y)=\int_0^1 (y-x)f(x)dx
> $$
> Find the nullspace of $T$ and the transpose $T^T$

If $f(y)\in Range(T)$ then
$$
Tf(y)=\int_0^1 (y-x)f(x)dx=y\int_0^1 f(x)dx-\int_0^1 xf(x)dx\\
$$
where $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ and $\int_0^1 xf(x)dx$ are scalars, so $Tf(y)$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $y$

Therefore, range of T is the subspace $\text{span}\{1,y\}$

i.e., Range(T) is any polynomial $a+by$ of degree $\leq 1$

If $f(y)\in \text{Ker}(T)$
$$
Tf(y)=\int_0^1 (y-x)f(x)dx=y\int_0^1 f(x)dx-\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=0\\
\implies \int_0^1 f(x)dx=0=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx
$$
since $1,x$ are linearly independent.

How do I obtain the nullspace of T from the condition ?

Have no clue of defining the transpose of the given linear transformation ?

Comment: You're quite quick when your say that the range of $T$ is $V= \mathrm{span}\{1, x\}$. You have only shown in the question that it is a linear subspace of $V$. Regarding the transpose, do you know its definition? What is your issue to use this definition?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I meant to say $Range(T)=span(1,y)$, sorry it was a typo. I have also edited the post.

Comment: The kernel consists of functions $f$ orthogonal to $1$ and to $x.$

Comment: My understanding is that $NullSpace(T)\perp \text{Rowspace}(T)$ where $\text{Columnspace}(T)=\text{Range}(T)$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc $NullSpace(T)\perp \text{Columnspace}(T)$ happends when $T^T=T$ right ?

Comment: Right, it also happens when $T^T=-T.$

Answer (score 1):

The operator can be represented in the form $$Tf=\langle f,1\rangle \,x-\langle f,x\rangle\, 1$$
In general if $Au=\langle u,v\rangle\, w,$ then $A^*u=\langle u,w\rangle v.$ Therefore $$ T^*f =\langle f,x\rangle 1 -\langle f,1\rangle\,x = -Tf$$ i.e. $T^*=-T.$ We have
$$Tf =\langle f,1\rangle \,\left(x-{1\over 2}\right)+\left [ {1\over 2}\langle f,1\rangle -\langle f,x\rangle \right ]\,1$$ The functions $1$ and $x-{1\over 2}$ are orthogonal to each other. Therefore $f\in \ker T$ iff $\langle f,1\rangle =\langle f,x\rangle=0,$ i.e. $f\perp 1,\,x.$

Comment: How do you say that $Au=<u,v>w$ and how does it imply that $A^*u=<u,w>v$ ?